# undefined reference to `crypt' in Eclipse IDE

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, gcc

crypt function for data encryption (using eclipse IDE) is giving me errors in this line of my **C** code
`crypt("password", pwd->sp_pwdp);`
 It says that it is undefined. I got the same error when I tried the same code in ubuntu with gcc ( **gcc test.c**) ,  I guess is linker error because it worked fine in ubuntu when I tried this 
`gcc test.c -lcrypt`
Man page for script tells us to link with -lcrypt.
 But how can I resolve this issue in eclipse IDE/ how can i link -lcrypt in eclipse ?

Comment: Did you add the proper library in eclipse's build configuration ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the library to the linker options in the project settings. In my version of Eclipse, that's:

Project -> Properties -> C/C++ Build -> Settings -> Tool Settings -> Linker -> Libraries

Add `crypt` to the "Libraries (-l)" panel.

Comment: I reached there and there are two frames , one with Libraries(-l) and other with Library search path(-L).. what should I enter , just crypt will do or ??

Comment: @user2723949: `crypt` in the Libraries panel.